# Calendar time convertation

Tags: java, android, calendar, datetime-format

Something strange happens when I am trying to convert date to a milliseconds. Maybe someone can explain my this:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(2017, 9, 3, 4, 50);

 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss",
     Locale.getDefault());
 Log.i("tag", formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

> and logcat logs my out:
>
> I/tag: 2017.10.03 04:50:34

Why months are different ?

Comment: Months are zero-based in `Calendar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar` month is zero-based (0-11) but when displayed it's in "human" version (1-12).

Comment: It means that I have to subtract 1 from month 9. Thanks

Comment: Yes, 8 stands for September, 9 for October, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the method `calendar.set()`, from the documentation the parameter month starts from 0.

> month the value used to set the `MONTH` calendar field.
>        * Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.